# PHP MYSQLi Array no select html

Tags: php, html, array, mysqli

Sou iniciante em php e estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema para minha empresa e que já serve como estudo, pois gosto muito desse área, a dúvida é simples, tenho o código abaixo:

```
<?php
include('conn/conexao.php');
$edt = $_GET['edital'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM edt_cadastro WHERE id = $edt";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num = $res->num_rows;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  $dados = $res->fetch_array();
  $arrRefs[$dados['id']] = $dados['ref0'];
}
?>

<label>Referências:</label>
<select name="ref" id="ref">
  <?php foreach($arrRefs as $value => $nome){
    echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$nome}</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

com esse código ele identifica a opção de um select anterior para carregar esse select acima (com jQuery), até ai funciona certinho, só que o valor que vem do banco para esse select, vem como um array exemplo `"1,2,3"` eu gostaria que ele me mostrasse um lista com 1 depois o 2, o 3 e assim por diante, no banco está separado com virgula "," (1,2,3) eu já tentei usar a opção explode porém dai na lista só aparece o ultimo registo no meu exemplo o número 3. alguém poderia de ajudar? obrigado

Comment: galera consegui, com o seguinte cod:
<?php
include('conn/conexao.php');
$edt = $_GET['edital'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM edt_cadastro WHERE id = $edt";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$i = 0;

?>

<label>Referências:</label>
<select name="ref" id="ref">
  <?php while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
 $referencias = $row['ref0'];
 $quantidade_ref = explode(",",$referencias);
 $total=count($quantidade_ref);
 $n = 0;
 while($n < $total)
 {
 $i++;
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$quantidade_ref[$n];
 $n++;
 } 
  
}
?>
</select>

Comment: Denis, se conseguiste resolver podes colocar a solucão como resposta (e não como comentário) ou então podes apagar a pergunta. Bom Ano Novo!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui, com o seguinte cod:

```
<?php           
include('conn/conexao.php');
$edt = $_GET['edital'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM edt_cadastro WHERE id = $edt";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$i = 0;
?>
<label>Referências:</label>
    <select name="ref" id="ref">
        <?php while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
            $referencias = $row['ref0'];
            $quantidade_ref = explode(",",$referencias);
            $total=count($quantidade_ref);
            $n = 0;
            while($n < $total) {
                $i++;
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$quantidade_ref[$n];
                $n++;
            }           
        }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Recomendo não utilizar a query como você está fazendo.
Leia sobre PreparedStatement.

Comment: Não seria melhor eliminar o `$n` e fazer simplesmente `echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$quantidade_ref[++$i];` ? Ou melhor ainda, no lugar do `while($n<$total)` um `for($i=0; $i<$total;$i++)`...